Changing the size of the content view in a zoomable/pan-able UIScrollView
I have a component that displays a UIView inside a UIScrollView and makes the view zoomable and pan-able. In general, the component works well, but there's a case where it breaks pretty significantly:

If the size of the UIView changes, I can't figure out how to "reset" the scroll view to a default state again and "start over" so that the displayed view is displayed in aspectRatio: fit and is zoomable pan-able from that state again.
The catch is that this does work if instead of changing the size of the UIView, I create a completely new UIView to display and completely recreate the entire scroll view component. (If I do just one of these, like just recreating the scroll view and not the displayed UIView, it doesn't work).

Here's some reproducible code that runs a simple demo. In it, the displayed UIView changes size every 3 seconds. If the two lines marked with // <-- HERE are included, everything "works", but if they aren't included, it breaks, and the new size, when first displayed, does not fit its aspect ratio to the screen.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var viewSize: CGSize = .init(width: 1440, height: 900)
    @State private var view: UIView = Self.generateTestView()
    
    let sizes: [CGSize] = [.init(width: 100, height: 800), .init(width: 1000, height: 1000), .init(width: 1440, height: 900)]
    
    static func generateTestView() -> UIView {
        let v = UIView()
        
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow].randomElement()!
        v.layer.borderWidth = 20
        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        
        return v
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollableUIViewRepresented(image: view,
                                        size: viewSize,
                                        containerSize: proxy.size)
            .id("\(viewSize.width)x\(viewSize.height)") // <-- HERE
        }
        .task {
            var v = 0
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC * 3)
            
            while true {
                view.frame = .zero
                view.removeFromSuperview()
                
                // view = Self.generateTestView() // <-- HERE
                
                viewSize = sizes[v % 3]
                v += 1
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC * 3)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollableUIViewRepresented: UIViewRepresentable {
    let image: UIView
    let size: CGSize
    let containerSize: CGSize
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ScrollableUIView {
        ScrollableUIView()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ScrollableUIView, context: Context) {
        view.display(image: image, size: size, containerSize: containerSize)
    }
}

final class ScrollableUIView: UIScrollView {
    private(set) var zoomView: UIView? = nil
    
    private(set) var imageSize: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    private(set) var containerSize: CGSize = .zero
    private(set) var maxScaleFromMinScale: CGFloat = 3.0
    
    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }
    
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    private func initialize() {
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        bouncesZoom = true
        decelerationRate = .fast
        delegate = self
    }
    
    public func adjustFrameToCenter() {
        guard let zoomView else {
            return
        }
        
        var frameToCenter = zoomView.frame
        
        // center horizontally
        if frameToCenter.size.width < containerSize.width {
            frameToCenter.origin.x = (containerSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2
        }
        else {
            frameToCenter.origin.x = 0
        }
        
        // center vertically
        if frameToCenter.size.height < containerSize.height {
            frameToCenter.origin.y = (containerSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2
        }
        else {
            frameToCenter.origin.y = 0
        }
        
        zoomView.frame = frameToCenter
    }
    
    // MARK: - Display image
    
    func display(image: UIView, size: CGSize, containerSize: CGSize) {
        print("Display", size, containerSize)
        if zoomView == nil {
            zoomView = image
            addSubview(zoomView!)
        }
        if size != imageSize {
            zoomView?.frame = .init(origin: .zero, size: size)
        }
        
        configureImageForSize(size, containerSize: containerSize)
    }
    
    private func configureImageForSize(_ size: CGSize, containerSize: CGSize) {
        imageSize = size
        self.containerSize = containerSize
        contentSize = imageSize
        
        // calculate min/max zoom scale
        let xScale = containerSize.width / imageSize.width    // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image width-wise
        let yScale = containerSize.height / imageSize.height   // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image height-wise
        
        var minScale: CGFloat = min(xScale, yScale)
        
        let maxScale = maxScaleFromMinScale*minScale
        
        // don't let minScale exceed maxScale. (If the image is smaller than the screen, we don't want to force it to be zoomed.)
        if minScale > maxScale {
            minScale = maxScale
        }
        
        maximumZoomScale = 3
        minimumZoomScale = minScale * 0.999 // the multiply factor to prevent user cannot scroll page while they use this control in UIPageViewController
        
        zoomScale = minimumZoomScale
        contentOffset =  CGPoint.zero
    }
}

extension ScrollableUIView: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    public func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    public func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return zoomView
    }
    
    public func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        adjustFrameToCenter()
    }
}

The code is reduced to the smallest footprint I can find that retains the behavior of the view and the problem
The two lines that "fix" the issue:
.id("\(viewSize.width)x\(viewSize.height)")

view = Self.generateTestView()

In my real app, it would be ideal if I didn't have to do what I see as a "hack" of recreating the displayed view and scroll view component.
Is there a way to modify my ScrollableUIView so that when display is called with a new size or containerSize, it can "reset" it's state and display the new sizes correctly?
Correctly displayed size (note that the entire border is visible):

Incorrectly displayed size:

